# Unit test for custom UICollectionViewLayout in swift

Tags: unit-testing, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, swift2

I have a custom layout class (e.g Mylayout) and setting it in collection view. In my test, how can I test that collection view layout is of type MyLayout?

Could any one help me how to test this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The collection view has a property `collectionViewLayout` which you can use to get the layout, and then it's just a case of making sure it's of the right class:

```
XCTAssertNotNil(collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? <your custom layout class>)
```